# How to show that $ \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (\mathcal{M}, \mathbb{R}) $ is a nuclear space ?.

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, manifolds, tensor-products, nuclear-norm

Let $ \mathcal{M} $ be a compact differential manifold.

Let $ A = \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (\mathcal{M}, \mathbb{R}) $ be the space of smooth functions over $ \mathcal{M} $.

How to show that $ A $ is a nuclear space ?.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please provide some context for this question? What have you tried so far? Which definition have you been trying to work with, and which of the properties within that definition have given you difficulty?

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to learn a little about Grothendieck's contribution to mathematics in the matter of nuclear spaces that he invented, and on this thread, http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~kazhdan/QFT/nuclear.pdf
we specify that $ \mathcal{C}^{\infty} (\mathcal{M}, \mathbb{R}) $ is a nuclear space without any detail.

Comment: Very interesting question, thanks for asking it. I suspect it would be helpful to use the fact that $C^\infty(\mathcal M,\Bbb R)$ [is a Frechet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space#From_smooth_manifolds), but I don't have any concrete ideas.

Comment: An idea that might help from the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space#Definition) on nuclear spaces: *It is not necessary to check this condition for all seminorms p; it is sufficient to check it for a set of seminorms that generate the topology, in other words, a set of seminorms that are a subbase for the topology.*

Comment: The proof should be similar to the proof used in the case of a torus, with the eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator taking the role of the exponential functions.